# Magento 2 custom routing frontend not working (100 router match iterations)

Tags: magento2, module, custom, routing, routes

I have used this url to change it but i am keeping getting the same erros
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209478/96152

i have a custom routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="testurl" frontName="testurl">
            <module name="Test_CustomRouter" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I have added frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customrouter" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Test\CustomRouter\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">61</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This is my controller for the router

```
class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory
     */
    protected $actionFactory;

    /**
     * Response
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $_response;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * Validate and Match
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return bool
     */
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        if (strpos($identifier, 'newcustomurl') !== false) {
            $request->setModuleName('customurl')->setControllerName('test')->setActionName('test');

        } else {
            return;
        }


        return $this->actionFactory->create(
                        'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward', ['request' => $request]
        );
    }

}
```

When i go to my frontent i get

> Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Please can i get some advice or where i am getting this wrong.